# Inductor circuit

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electric-current, inductance, electromagnetic-induction

> Consider a inductor circuit with an inductor connected to a DC battery and a switch. Initially the switch is open.
>   At time $t=0$ the switch is closed. What will happen to the inductor just after the switch is closed?
>
> 1. compress
> 2. expand
> 3. nothing will happen

Answer (score 1):

Well if you keep lenz's law in mind ( hope i spelled it right). Then it will expand for just a small sec and then it will come back to its original self because of the sudden change in flux and current but since DC has no frequency so it will stabilize.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what is meant by the statement "just after the switch is closed".

If that statement means the current is zero then nothing happens to the inductor.

When there is a current passing through the inductor then conductors on opposite sides will repel one another because the currents are in opposite directions so the inductor will expand but adjacent turns with the currents in the same direction will attract one another and so the inductor will compress.
The effect due to the interactions between the current will increase with time reaching a maximum when the current through the circuit has reached a maximum.